# Smokeping make install error

Tags: make-install

i try to install newest version smokeping and get error when run "make install". I do everything as written on the official website.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/artemto/smokeping-2.7.2/thirdparty'
echo "If the moduile install hangs, this may be because one of the modules expects you to press [return] without telling you ... just do it!"
If the moduile install hangs, this may be because one of the modules expects you to press [return] without telling you ... just do it!
  GEN      touch
! Installing FCGI failed. See /home/artemto/smokeping-2.7.2/thirdparty/work/1533497827.2903/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
CGI is up to date. (4.38)
CGI::Fast is up to date. (2.13)
Config::Grammar is up to date. (1.12)
! Configure failed for Socket6-0.28. See /home/artemto/smokeping-2.7.2/thirdparty/work/1533497827.2903/build.log for details.
IO::Socket::SSL is up to date. (2.056)
Digest::HMAC_MD5 is up to date. (1.01)
Net::Telnet is up to date. (3.04)
Net::OpenSSH is up to date. (0.77)
Net::SNMP is up to date. (v6.0.1)
! Installing Text::Soundex failed. See /home/artemto/smokeping-2.7.2/thirdparty/work/1533497827.2903/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution GSSAPI
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Text::Soundex' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for perl-ldap-0.65.
Net::DNS is up to date. (1.15)
! Configure failed for IO-Tty-1.12. See /home/artemto/smokeping-2.7.2/thirdparty/work/1533497827.2903/build.log for details.
LWP is up to date. (6.33)
Authen::Radius is up to date. (0.26)
Path::Tiny is up to date. (0.104)
Makefile:410: recipe for target 'touch' failed
make[1]: *** [touch] Error 123
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/artemto/smokeping-2.7.2/thirdparty'
Makefile:363: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. Furthermore it is completely unclear what you talk about. What programming language? What are you trying to do? etc. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, sorry for make this quickly post

```
apt install gcc
```

Answer (score 0):

I get similar problem on Debian 9.5 and smokeping-2.7.2.tar.gz . 
Installed the following packages prior to compilation and I assume some other package is missing but which?

```
apt-get install rrdtool curl perl make gcc
curl is already the newest version (7.52.1-5+deb9u6).
gcc is already the newest version (4:6.3.0-4).
make is already the newest version (4.1-9.1).
perl is already the newest version (5.24.1-3+deb9u4).
rrdtool is already the newest version (1.6.0-1+b2).


...
Successfully installed Data-HexDump-0.02
Successfully installed Authen-Radius-0.26
Successfully installed Path-Tiny-0.104
37 distributions installed
Makefile:410: recipe for target 'touch' failed
make[1]: *** [touch] Error 123
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cisadmin/smokeping/thirdparty'
Makefile:363: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
root@l-mog-horch:/home/cisadmin/smokeping#
```

EDIT

It works fine with 2.7.1 so something is wrong in the 2.7.2 package...